# Need to double check if I understood how Github works

Tags: github

Alright, I am just starting as a python programmer, I am setting up my github and forking some projects I'd like to use with my own variations, so far what I think I am understanding is the following:

1. You have your code on github
2. That code has a built in URL system that calls those folders and works on them on the desktop version of github, the one you use on your computer
3. the IDE of your choice can sync with github via a simple command line that calls the url that contains the code.
4. once you build the code on your local github install on your desktop you push that code to github again
5. that code (somehow, I haven't studied that part yet) connects to a domain name, via namecheap and stuff.

I am way off, close enough? deluding myself?

many tutorials on youtube just assume everyone already know this, but for me even the most simple and braindead things are a huge google rabbit hole.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Think of a git repository, like those hosted by GitHub, as a remote copy of a project, where every file's changes are remembered. You work on the local copy of your files, and `commit` copies of those files to the remote repository every time you have something worth saving.

You can share the remote repository with others, and when they `clone` a copy to their local machine they get to see every commit you made, and the current state of every file in the repository. They can rewind some or all of the repository to any previous point in time.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

2. Git record all changes of your code once you commit, all info stored in .git folder hidden in your root directory. Github is just a place where you store/share it. No difference between desktop or commandline
3. Git doesn't care what IDE you use
4. Any change you made with code, you have to push it so Github will store it.
5. You have to use Github Webhook for that. Otherwise Github is just a place you store your code.